# Coherent states - scalar product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, coherent-states

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$
$\newcommand\ket[1]{|#1\rangle}$
$\newcommand\mean[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$
$\newcommand\braket[2]{\langle #1|#2\rangle}$
$\newcommand\ketbra[2]{|#1\rangle\langle #2|}$

One shows that the wave-function of the coherent states of a system can be written in terms of a Gaussian function, as follows
\begin{equation}
\label{general wave-function}
\psi(x) = \frac{\exp(-\frac{i}{2\pi}\mean{X}\mean{P})}{\left(\pi l^2\right)^{1/4}}\exp(-\frac{\left(x-\mean{X}\right)^2}{2l^2}+\frac{i\mean{P}x}{\hbar})
\end{equation}
where we have $l=\sqrt{2}\Delta X$.

Independently, one shows that $\psi(x) = \braket{x}{\psi}$ and that $\psi(x)$ is indeed a coherent state, in the sense that $\ket{\psi}=\ket{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$ in the complex plane.

One might wonder what $\braket{0}{\alpha}$ could possibly mean. Using the creation and annihilation operators introduced to solve the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator, one shows that the solution to this question is given by $\braket{0}{\alpha} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\norm{\alpha}^2}$.

**My question concerns the proof that $\braket{0}{\alpha}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\norm{\alpha}^2}$**, using the wave-function introduced above. Here is how I tried to do it.

I start by using the well-known relation
\begin{align}
\mathbb{I} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; \ketbra{x}{x},
\end{align}
which I shall refer to as the completing relationship.

\begin{align}
\braket{x}{\alpha} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \; \braket{0}{x}\braket{x}{\alpha}
\end{align}

Let us note that $\braket{0}{x}$ is the fundamental state of the Harmonic Oscillator, which is an established function (just plug-in $x=0$ in the first equation). One finds oneself having to deal with a Gaussian integral, which one can readily resolve as

\begin{align} 
\braket{0}{\alpha} &= \exp(-\frac{i}{2\hbar}\mean{X}\mean{P}-\frac{\mean{X}^2}{2l^2}+\frac{\alpha^2}{2}) = \exp(-\frac{\alpha\mean{X}}{\sqrt{2}l}+\frac{\norm{\alpha}^2}{2})
\end{align}
where I used the fact that $\alpha = \mean{a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\mean{X}}{l}+\frac{il\mean{P}}{\hbar}\right)$.

I don't know how I can go further, without previously knowing the expected result. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is a relationship between $\alpha$ and $\langle X\rangle$ and $\langle P\rangle$ which can be derived using the fact that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of the lowering operator and that the lowering operator can be written in term so the operators $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$. Use that!

Comment: @march : I updated the question following your advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you check my solution below? @march

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\renewcommand\inf{\infty}$
$\renewcommand\ket[1]{|#1\rangle}$
$\renewcommand\ketbra[2]{|#1\rangle\langle#2|}$
$\renewcommand\braket[2]{\langle #1|#2 \rangle}$
$\renewcommand\mean[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$
$\renewcommand\expval[1]{\mean{#1}}$
$\renewcommand\h{\hbar}$
$\renewcommand\norm[1]{||#1||}$

I have found two methods to answer this. The most general method uses the wave-function associated with a coherent state. It is given by
\begin{equation}
\braket{x}{\psi} = \psi(x) = \frac{\exp(-\frac{i}{2\pi}\mean{X}\mean{P})}{\left(\pi l^2\right)^{1/4}}\exp(-\frac{\left(x-\mean{X}\right)^2}{2l^2}+\frac{i\mean{P}x}{\h})
\end{equation}
where $l = 2\Delta X$.

**Resolution using a gaussian integral**

In the X-representation of Quantum Mechanics, one has the closure relation
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\inf}^{+\inf}dx \; \ketbra{x}{x}
\end{equation}

Using this property, one was find a solution to $\ketbra{0}{\alpha}$. Indeed,
\begin{equation}
\ketbra{0}{\alpha} = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} dx \; \braket{0}{x}\braket{x}{\alpha}
\end{equation}
The term $\braket{x}{0}$ is known as the fundamental state of a coherent state. The second ($\braket{x}{\alpha}$) is the wave-function given here-above. Doing the math, one finds
\begin{align*}
  \braket{0}{\alpha} &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \; \left(\frac{\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2l^2})}{\left(\pi l^2\right)^{1/4}}\right)\left[\frac{\exp(-\frac{i}{2\pi}\expval{X}\expval{P})}{\left(\pi l^2\right)^{1/4}}\exp(-\frac{\left(x-\expval{X}\right)^2}{2l^2}+\frac{i\expval{P}x}{\hbar})\right]\\
  &= \frac{\exp(-\frac{i}{2\pi}\expval{X}\expval{P}-\frac{\expval{X}^2}{2l^2})}{l\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \; \exp(-\left(\frac{x}{l}\right)^2+x\underbrace{\left(\frac{\expval{X}}{l^2}+\frac{i\expval{P}}{\h}\right)}_{\frac{\sqrt{2}\alpha}{l}})
\end{align*}

We then have a Gaussian integral, which can be solved explicitely into:
\begin{align*}
  \braket{0}{\alpha} &= \frac{\exp(-\frac{i}{2\pi}\expval{X}\expval{P}-\frac{\expval{X}^2}{2l^2})}{l\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\pi}l\exp(\frac{\alpha^2}{2}) = e^{-\frac{\norm{\alpha}^2}{2}}
\end{align*}

**Resolution using properties of coherent states**

For any complex number $\alpha$, one has that $\ket{\alpha} = e^{-\norm{\alpha}^2/2}\sum_n \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\ket{n}$.
Using this property, the proof requested is trivial:
\begin{equation}
\braket{0}{\alpha} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\norm{\alpha}^2}\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\ketbra{0}{n} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\norm{\alpha}^2}
\end{equation}
where one uses the fact that $\braket{0}{n} = 0$ for all $n\neq 0$.